# No built-in pull quote template in Microsoft Word for Mac

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using Microsoft for Mac version 16.51, and I want to put a pull quote in my document. I'm watching [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=pull%20quote%20in%20word&oq=pull%20quote%20in%20word&aqs=chrome.0.0i20i263i512j0i512j0i22i30l7j0i390.5078j1j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_ivkOYd3VKP7F0PEP-uCb0As60) tutorial video, and I can see there are different built-in options the tutor can choose from, but all I can see are two options: Draw text box, Draw vertical text box.
Why is there such discrepancy, and where can I find these built-in templates for pull quotes in Microsoft Word?

Comment: Have I answered your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: As Charles Kenyon replied, currently Word for Mac does not have Text Box Gallery.

Answer (score 1):

### Those are "building blocks" and are not yet available in Word for the Mac.

*Your Tutorial uses Word for Windows.* You can create a text box in an existing document and save it as an AutoText entry on the Mac.

If you would like, I can build a template with such AutoText entries for you and you could save it as a [Global Template](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global) on your system. You would then be able to use them, again, as AutoText. *The link is to a page on my website.*

[EDIT]
Here is a [link to my downloads page](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#QuotationSidebar) where you can download a template that contains all of the quotation and sidebar textboxes from the Windows versions saved as AutoText. I created such the template in Word for Windows using the Building Blocks Organizer to change the gallery of the Text Boxes to AutoText.

Here is a list from that template of the available textboxes:

[image: screenshot]

I've added an [Article on this on the Microsoft website](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/textbox-templates-not-available-on-word-for-the/c3bc6474-6beb-4ab4-b6f7-4017b351e827).